# Create auto calculation by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a simple calculation by receiving the data from previous page. Here is the first page and it is sending the data after click check out.

```
    <script>
        function passValues() {
            var bp = document.getElementById("Amount_BP").value;
            localStorage.setItem("bp_value", bp);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
            <form action="settlement.aspx">
                <table style="width:60%";>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Black pepper sauce
                            <br />
                            Amount: <input type="number" id="Amount_BP" value="0" style="margin-top: 5px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
<button type="button" class="settlement button_press" onclick="settlement(); passValues();">Check Out</button>
```

And the second page is the settlement so it will receive the amount from the previous page. And I want make it the calculation auto complete after receive data. The script below the table is receive data script.

```
            <table style="width:90%">
                <tr>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="Image/chicken_chop.png" style="height: 100px; width: 200px"/></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">Black Pepper Sauce</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center"><p id="Amount_bp" onchange="autoCal(this.value)">0</p></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input class="w3-input w3-border" name="tot_amount" id="total" type="text" readonly/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("Amount_bp").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("bp_value");
    </script>
```

And the last one is my script file that I created for both

```
function settlement () {
    window.location.href = 'settlement.aspx';
}

function autoCal(val) {
    var tot_price = val * 14.9;
    /*display the result*/
    var divobj = document.getElementById('total');
    divobj.value = tot_price;
}
```

At the last, I think that it is work for me as I expect the data send to another page and it will auto calculate but it fail. I think my problem is on `function autoCal(Val)` that part but I can't find the mistake I made

Comment: I guess that last statement of the autoCal function is wrong. Try divobj.innerHTML instead of `divobj.value

Comment: @theLibertine Thanks but it didn't work =(

Comment: Could you please explain the expected behavior and what is going wrong? Is the value not displaying?

Comment: The `document.getElementById('total').value = tot_price` is correct, but why is there a onchange on a P?

Comment: @theLibertine YA. So I expect the amount as data will send to settlement.aspx. And the settlement.aspx will received the data and auto calculate the price. But my code seems didn't auto calculate and didn't display it as well.

Comment: `onchange="autoCal(this.value)"` a `<p>` does not have a value use `innerHTML`. Maybe you ment this to be a `<input type="text" onchange="autoCal(this.value)" value="0"/>` ?

Comment: @JelleBruisten That is because I make that p is receiving the data from previous page and the onchange event is the data change for the function that autoCal(val)

Comment: @JelleBruisten It didn't works and also cannot receive the data from the previous page.

Comment: I see you are calling `passValues()` function on click of the first page. Could you show us this function?  
Also, you are trying to pass a value from a page to another, but you can't keep values between pages in a js variable, because they are re-initialized at every page load.

Comment: your onChange not going to work anymore.

Comment: You need to call passValue(); before settlement(); in the onclick otherwise you'll got to the settlement page before the value is stored.

Comment: @theLibertine Ya I showed it at the top of the first page. The function passValues() in the script

Comment: @MattEllen Ermm but how? Also my data got store inside the localStorage ya. As the data I put at the first page, the second page will display the data from the localStorage. But my function autoCal didn't work.

Comment: where you have `onclick="settlement(); passValues();"` change it to `onclick="passValues(); settlement();"`. Your second page can't display data if you don't put the data in there. as I said, you leave the page before the data gets saved to local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works perfect for your problem.

**First Page**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>

</head>
<body>
     <form action="second.html" method="POST">
                <table style="width:60%";>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Black pepper sauce
                            <br />
                            Amount: <input type="number" id="Amount_BP" value="0" style="margin-top: 5px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form >
<button type="button" class="settlement button_press" onclick=" testJS();"> Check Out</button>
</body>
</html>

<script>
        function testJS() {
    var b = document.getElementById('Amount_BP').value;
        url = 'file:///var/www/html/Stack/second.html';
        localStorage.setItem("bp_value", b);
        document.location.href = url;
}
</script>
```

**Second Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
         <table style="width:90%">
                <tr>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">Black Pepper Sauce</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center"><p id="Amount_bp" onchange="autoCal(this.value)">0</p></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input class="w3-input w3-border" name="tot_amount" id="total" type="text" readonly/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("Amount_bp").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("bp_value");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        console.log("hello");
        var tot_price = localStorage.getItem("bp_value") * 14.9;
    /*display the result*/
    var divobj = document.getElementById('total');
    divobj.value = tot_price;
}
</script>
```

Please let me know if this is not working.

Comment: Owhh. It's work! Thank you. I found out where the problem is. I should use the data from the localStorage in the script right?

Comment: Yes exactly @JohnLee

Comment: Thank you! You help me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I made this quick:

first page:

```
<script>
        function passValues() {
            var bp = document.getElementById("Amount_BP").value;
            localStorage.setItem("bp_value", bp);
            return false;
        }

function settlement () {
    window.location.href = 'index2.html';
}       
    </script>
            <form action="settlement.aspx">
                <table style="width:60%";>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Black pepper sauce
                            <br />
                            Amount: <input type="number" id="Amount_BP" value="0" style="margin-top: 5px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
<button type="button" class="settlement button_press" onclick="settlement(); passValues();">Check Out</button>
```

and the second page:

```
    <table style="width:90%">
                <tr>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="Image/chicken_chop.png" style="height: 100px; width: 200px"/></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">Black Pepper Sauce</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center"><input type="number" id="Amount_bp" onchange="autoCal(this.value)" value="0"/></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input class="w3-input w3-border" name="tot_amount" id="total" type="text" readonly/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("Amount_bp").value = localStorage.getItem("bp_value");
        document.getElementById("total").value = localStorage.getItem("bp_value") * 14,9;
function autoCal(val) {
    var tot_price = val * 14.9;
    console.log(tot_price);
    /*display the result*/
    var divobj = document.getElementById('total');
    divobj.value = tot_price;
}       
</script>
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: YA! It is work as I add this line ```document.getElementById("total").value = localStorage.getItem("bp_value") * 14,9;```

Comment: Btw Both of your answer and another answer are work for me!! Thanks for your kind reply.